# print n times number from 1. Need print (1 2 2 3 3 3 4)

Tags: kotlin

I can't figure out how to solve the following problem: there is a number n. Output the numbers to the console in order separated by a space, but so that the next digit in the iteration is output as many times as it is a digit, and at the same time so that there are no more than n digits in the output. Сan anyone suggest the correct algorithm?

example: have n = 7, need print (1 2 2 3 3 3 4) in kotlin

what i try:

```
var n = 7
var count = 1
var i = 1

    for (count in 1..n) {
        for (i in 1..count) {
                print(count)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var n = 11
var count = 1
var i = 1
var size = 0
    // loop@ for naming a loop in kotlin and inside another loop we can break or continue from outer loop   
  loop@  for (count in 1..n) {
        for (i in 1..count) {
                print(count)
                size++
                if (size == n){
                    break@loop
                }
                
        }
    }
```

You can use  "@" for naming loops and if you want to break from that loop, you can use this syntax in kotlin. It worked for me.
For kotlin labeled break you can look at this reference: [link](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/break)

Comment: You are welcome, it was nothing :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 1
var n = 7
for(count in 1..n) {
    print(count.toString().repeat(count))
}
```

`count.toString()` converts an integer to a string, `.repeat()` function repeats `count` times the string.

In case you need to add a space between each number, you can add the following:
`print(" ")`

Answer (score 1):

Using [`generateSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html) and [Collections](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/) functions:

```
val n = 7
println(generateSequence(1) {it + 1}
                 .flatMap{e -> List(e){e}}
                 .take(n)
                 .joinToString(" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is correct, You have to put a space between the printing

you can follow the code from this link
[Kotlin lang code snippet](https://%20https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS44LjEwIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiLyoqXG4gKiBZb3UgY2FuIGVkaXQsIHJ1biwgYW5kIHNoYXJlIHRoaXMgY29kZS5cbiAqIHBsYXkua290bGlubGFuZy5vcmdcbiAqL1xuZnVuIG1haW4oKSB7XG4gICAgdmFyIG4gPSA3XG52YXIgY291bnQgPSAxXG52YXIgaSA9IDFcblxuICAgIGZvciAoY291bnQgaW4gMS4ubikge1xuICAgICAgICBmb3IgKGkgaW4gMS4uY291bnQpIHtcbiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBwcmludChjb3VudClcbiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBwcmludCgnICcpXG4gICAgICAgIH1cbiAgICB9XG5cbn0ifQ==)

or the following code snippet

```
fun main() {
var n = 7
var count = 1
var i = 1

for (count in 1..n) {
    for (i in 1..count) {
            print(count)
            print(' ')
    }
}
```

}

Comment: but according to the task, the output to the console should end exactly after the 7th digit, that is, the output should not be 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7, but 1 2 2 3 3 3 4

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's another approach where you write your own sequence function which produces individual values on demand (instead of creating intermediate lists)

```
sequence {
    var digit = 1
    while (true) {
        for (i in 1..digit) yield(digit)
        digit++
    }
}.take(7)
.joinToString(" ")
.run(::print)
```

Not a big deal in this situation, but good to know!